# http requests with answer 0 url null ionic 3

Tags: angular, http, express, ionic-framework, cors

I have my REST API done in Node.js (Express) which URL is http: // localhost: 3000, my configuration of cors de
My REST API
is:

```
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
```

Then in my ionic application when I start ** ionic serce -c ** on my browser on my PC all the HTTP requests which work, I use ** HttpClientModule ** for them
[IonicDev App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.ionic.devapp&fbclid=IwAR13rZFXx9zZqEE29W3kyGdm2mZBu9dXC72GvWugQsW7HGq92vEoHJfAJyI)

or in the Android Studio emulator I receive an error

```
{“data”: null, “status”: 0, “config”: {“method”: “GET”, “transformRequest”: [null], “transformResponse”: [null], “Accept”: “ application / json ”,“ Content-Type ”:“ application / json ”,“ url ”:“
```

I've also tried creating a proxy in ** ionic.config.json **
but it keeps throwing the same error

```
"proxies": [
  {
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "http://aqui.com/api"
  }
]
```

Comment: could you copy the API request once from Web and once from Android Emulator into the description? Did you check if it is a CORS origin file error?

Comment: Hi @Crhonos Magdalena. Have you configure the endpoints in the ionic code in order to make the request to the ip and not to localhost?

Comment: So, do I configure the endpoints from the ip that is assigned to my cell phone?

Comment: The error status 0 and URL null only leave me since I try it on my phone because in the web browser I'm doing everything right as I understood it on the phone works as localhost: 8080 and that's why the cors blocks it

Comment: Will I be setting up my CORS or will it be IONIC?